# Need help in writing a Junit test (mock) for a source code using CompleteableFuture

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, mockito, completable-future

*Objective is to write a unit test case with mocks for a code having CompleteableFuture based Async operation.*
Referred to various examples (including stackoverflow), did not find any information. *Most of the examples in books, various online sources and also in stack overflow point to usage of CompleteableFuture in the test code.*

Here I am looking to mock unit test for source code having a completableFuture.

Please provide any pointers, if you have.

### Source code targeted for unit test :-

```java
public String getSomeResultThruAsync(Integer a) {

        CompletableFuture<String> resultFuture;
        resultFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(a);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw new CustomException("custom code and message");
            }

        }, executorService);    // custom executorService initialized separately; to use apart from common pool 
        return resultFuture.complete();
    }

}
```

### Unit test code with Mock (mockito) :-

```java
@Test
public void testGetSomeResultThruAsync()
    {
        // someFactory is a mock object of Factory class
        Mockito.when(someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(any(String.class))
               .thenReturn("test result");

        ...... Some base class code initialization, after that getSomeResultThruAsync method is called

    }
```

In usual cases above code works fine when mocked. 
*Here for completableFuture control never returns.*
I tried some other ways suggested by friends or colleagues. Result is pretty much same as above.

Comment: What’s the point of the `getSomeResultThruAsync` method in the first place? Why launching an asynchronous operation when blocking the calling thread anyway? By the way, your `return null;` statement is not only bad coding style, it’s invalid anyway, as the code location is unreachable. Further, there are inconsistencies regarding the parameter type of `getSomeResultMethod`; once you pass a `String`, then an `Integer`…

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete so it doesn't allow to reproduce your problem. Could you provide a [mre] instead? Also, have you tried debugging your test?

Comment: @Holger:  Removed the null return in the original question. In the actual method input is a dictionary has some details specific to Internal Team. And output is a processed information based on the result of getSomeResultMethod.

Comment: That doesn’t explain why you are using a `CompletableFuture` when you’re waiting for the result anyway. You can invoke `getSomeResultMethod` directly.

Comment: @Holger: Updated the code with the latest changes. Removed get and replaced with complete.  In the actual code, we are seeing 3 secs improvement. Now problem is in unit testing the source code. Are further pointers now ?

Comment: You surely haven’t tested that code as `resultFuture.complete()` won’t compile. [The only `complete` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete(T)) in `CompletableFuture` expects a value and returns a `boolean`. You really should start thinking about the semantics of the code. You’re tenaciously ignoring the question, why you’re initiating an asynchronous operation when you’re waiting for its result anyway, turning the whole operation into a synchronous one. And read my first comment again, *carefully*.

Comment: Thank you Holger and Didier for the inputs. Please note this code is of another friend, could not paste exact details for their confidentiality. Focus was on writing a unit testcase when completableFuture is used in the source. For now, their architect team agreed with 95% code coverage and so they parked this issue completely for future. If there is a way to mark the issue as Closed or Will not discuss , please do so.      @Holger: By the way, yes, complete call was there with return value and an input. Above code is more of a reference to original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you want to cover by unit tests following class:

```
private static class SomeClass {

    private final SomeFactory someFactory;
    private final Executor executorService;

    public SomeClass(SomeFactory someFactory, Executor executorService) {
        this.someFactory = someFactory;
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> getSomeResultAsync(Integer a) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(a);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CustomException("custom code and message");
            }
        }, executorService);
    }
}
```

This is how you can do it:

```
public class SomeClassTest {

    private Executor executor = Runnable::run; // same-thread executor
    private SomeFactory someFactory = Mockito.mock(SomeFactory.class);
    private SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(someFactory, executor);

    @Test
    public void someResultIsReturnedIfAsyncCallCompletesWithoutErrors() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(1)).thenReturn("test");

        CompletableFuture<String> resultAsync = someClass.getSomeResultAsync(1);
        String result = resultAsync.get();

        Assertions.assertThat(result).isEqualTo("test");
    }

    @Test
    public void customExceptionIsThrownIfAsyncCallFailesWithError() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> someClass.getSomeResultAsync(1).get())
                .isInstanceOf(ExecutionException.class)
                .hasCause(new CustomException("custom code and message"));
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. In the tests above `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` is used.
2. Your code sample from the question doesn't make much sense, because you basically just wrap `someFactory.getSomeResultMethod(a)` inside `CompletableFuture` and then call `complete` (I assume, you actually meant `get`). That's why I used another example to demonstrate the approach for unit testing `CompletableFuture`.